# How to read html desc parameter with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_param_value

I learned how to read parameter values of HTML elements but when I tried to get the value of desc of a link it outputs "undefined". It works with the title so I don't understand why it doesn't work with desc

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" desc="google" title="Google" id="myLink">Google</a>
```

and JavaScript:

```
let x = document.getElementById("myLink").desc;
console.log("value of desc: " + x);
```

Is there another way to read its value? I would prefer plain javascript but anything will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `desc` is non-standard attribute, it's not in DOM object.

Use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) for that

```js
let x = document.getElementById("myLink").getAttribute('desc');
console.log("value of desc: " + x);
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" desc="google" title="Google" id="myLink">Google</a>
```

---

Correct approach with custom attributes would be via [JS Dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Then your attribute would look like `data-desc="google"` and to access it:

```
// JS
document.getElementById("myLink").dataset.desc
document.getElementById("myLink").dataset.desc = 'bing'

// jQuery
$('#myLink').data('desc')
$('#myLink').data('desc', 'bing')

// CSS attr() :before|:after only
#myLink::before {
  content: attr(data-desc);
}

// CSS selector
#myLink[data-desc='google']
```

Comment: @WithoutHope Although `.getAttribute()` will "work", it is not correct to use non-standard HTML attributes. See my answer below for the correct way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Let's get some terminology down first and that may help you understand what's going on. HTML does not have "*parameters*". There are "*elements*", which may or may not have "*attributes*". In JavaScript, you have "*objects*", and they have "*properties*".

HTML is processed (parsed) by a different mechanism than JavaScript is and when you ask the JavaScript "engine" to process an HTML element, it creates an "object" representation of that "element" and just about all the "attributes" get copied into "properties" of the new object.

However, there is no such HTML attribute as "desc", so when the JavaScript object gets created, it doesn't get a `desc` property for you to access. Had you tried a different property that aligns with the valid attributes, it would have worked:

```js
var link = document.getElementById("myLink");

console.log(link.href); // works
console.log(link.title); // works
console.log(link.desc)  // doesn't work
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" desc="google" title="Google" id="myLink">Google</a>
```

Here's where things get tricky, although the JavaScript object representation of the HTML element doesn't get created with non-standard properties, the HTML element's non-standard attribute can still be accessed through JavaScript, by accessing the attributes of the HTML element directly:

```js
var link = document.getElementById("myLink");

console.log(link.getAttribute("desc"));
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" desc="google" title="Google" id="myLink">Google</a>
```

But there actually is a way to create *valid* custom attributes and access them through JavaScript using [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), which are attributes that start with `data-` and then you can append a custom attribute name on to that. Through this interface, there is then a standard way to access those attributes through the `dataset` property that all JavaScript objects that represent HTML elements will have:

```js
var link = document.getElementById("myLink");

// You can access a data- attribute through the
// dataset property
console.log(link.dataset.desc);
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" data-desc="google" title="Google" id="myLink">Google</a>
```

And, do yourself a big favor and stay as far away from W3Schools as you possibly can. The site is well known to have incomplete, outdated, or just plain incorrect information. Instead, learn from the most widely recognized authority on JavaScript, [The Mozilla Developers Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn).

Comment: Thanks for long terminology, but your answer does not even explain *how* to solve issue. And to suggest `try other properties` is wrong

Comment: @Justinas Clearly, you didn't read the answer. I never suggested to `try other properties`. I demonstrated how valid attributes will translate to valid properties and non-valid attributes won't. And *how to solve the issue* was explained as it was said that `desc` is not valid HTML (so don't use invalid HTML). But, if you kept reading the "long" answer, you would see that there is a way to get the value through the use of `getAttribute`. It's too bad that you'd rather make inaccurate complaints that try to learn something.